# Flow of Batch Apex Code

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

"BatchJob_Obs" Class

```
global class BatchJob_Obs implements Schedulable{ 
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
List<Operating_Business_Status__c> waiting_to_process_list = [SELECT  id,Future_Dated__c from Operating_Business_Status__c WHERE Effective_Date__c <=: System.Today() and Future_Dated__c = TRUE and (End_Date__c >=: System.Today() OR End_Date__c =:NULL) ORDER BY Effective_Date__c];
Integer no_of_batch_available = 5 - [SELECT count() FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType='BatchApex' AND (Status = 'Processing' OR Status = 'Preparing' OR Status = 'Queued')];

if(no_of_batch_available >= waiting_to_process_list.size()) {
  for(Operating_Business_Status__c obs_rec: waiting_to_process_list) {
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchUpdateOBS('(\'' + obs_rec.id + '\')'));
  }
}
else {
  for(Integer i=0;i<no_of_batch_available;i++) {
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchUpdateOBS('(\'' + waiting_to_process_list.get(i).id + '\')'));
  }

  BatchJob_Obs retry_sc = new BatchJob_Obs();
  String timeForScheduler = (Datetime.now() + (0.008103)).format('s m H d M \'?\' yyyy');
  Id schedId = System.Schedule('Batch_OBS'+timeForScheduler.replace(' ','_'),timeForScheduler,retry_sc);
}
}
}
```

"BatchUpdateOBS" Class

```
global class BatchUpdateOBS implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
String query='';
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
public BatchUpdateOBS(String query_input) {
 query = 'SELECT id, Future_Dated__c from Operating_Business_Status__c WHERE ID IN ' + query_input;
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
 BatchUpdate Obs_batch = new BatchUpdate();
 List<ID> OBSIDList = new List<ID>();
 List<Operating_Business_Status__c> OBSList = new List<Operating_Business_Status__c>();
 for(sObject s: scope) {
   Operating_Business_Status__c obs_rec = (Operating_Business_Status__c)s;
   obs_rec.Future_Dated__c = false;
   OBSIDList.add(obs_rec.id);
   OBSList.add(obs_rec);
 }
 if(!OBSIDList.isEmpty()) { Obs_batch.update_batch_status('Operating_Business_Status',OBSIDList, Database.Update(OBSList,false)); }
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

"BatchUpdate" class

```
global class BatchUpdate { 
String sandbox = '';
Map<ID,Account> AccountMap = new Map<ID,Account>();
public void BatchUpdate() {
String s = UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.').toUpperCase();
if(s == 'COM') { sandbox = 'PROD.'; }
else { sandbox = s + '.'; }
}
public void update_name() {
List<ID> NameIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Agency_Name__c> AgencyNameList = [SELECT id,Name,Is_Display_Name__c,Effective_Date__c,Agency__c,New_Agency_Name__c FROM Agency_Name__c WHERE Effective_Date__c <=: System.Today()];
for(Agency_Name__c AgencyRec : AgencyNameList){
  AgencyRec.Effective_Date__c = null;
  AgencyRec.Name = AgencyRec.New_Agency_Name__c;
  AgencyRec.New_Agency_Name__c = null;
  NameIDList.add(AgencyRec.id);
}
if(!NameIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Agency_Name',NameIDList, Database.Update(AgencyNameList,false)); }
}
public void update_phone() {
List<ID> PhoneIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Agency_Phone_Number__c> PhoneNumberList = [SELECT id,Agency__c,Currently_Used__c,New_Phone__c,Phone__c FROM Agency_Phone_Number__c WHERE Effective_Date__c <=: System.Today()];
for(Agency_Phone_Number__c PhoneNumberRec : PhoneNumberList){
  PhoneNumberRec.Effective_Date__c = null;
  PhoneNumberRec.Phone__c = PhoneNumberRec.New_Phone__c;
  PhoneNumberRec.New_Phone__c = null;
  PhoneIDList.add(PhoneNumberRec.id);
}
if(!PhoneIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Agency_Phone_Number',PhoneIDList, Database.Update(PhoneNumberList,false)); }
}
public void update_address() {
List<ID> AddressIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Agency_Address__c> AgencyAddressList = [SELECT id, Street__c, New_Street__c, City__c, New_City__c, County__c, New_County__c, State_Province__c, New_State_Province__c, Zip_Postal_Code__c, New_Zip_Postal_Code__c, Country__c, New_Country__c FROM Agency_Address__c WHERE Effective_Date__c <=: System.Today()];
for(Agency_Address__c agencyAddressRec : AgencyAddressList){
  agencyAddressRec.Street__c = agencyAddressRec.New_Street__c;
  agencyAddressRec.City__c = agencyAddressRec.New_City__c;
  agencyAddressRec.State_Province__c = agencyAddressRec.New_State_Province__c;
  agencyAddressRec.Zip_Postal_Code__c = agencyAddressRec.New_Zip_Postal_Code__c;
  agencyAddressRec.Country__c = agencyAddressRec.New_Country__c;
  agencyAddressRec.County__c = agencyAddressRec.New_County__c;   
  agencyAddressRec.New_Street__c = null;
  agencyAddressRec.New_City__c = null;
  agencyAddressRec.New_State_Province__c = null;
  agencyAddressRec.New_Zip_Postal_Code__c = null;
  agencyAddressRec.New_County__c  = null;
  agencyAddressRec.Effective_Date__c = null;
  AddressIDList.add(agencyAddressRec.id);
}
if(!AddressIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Agency_Address',AddressIDList, Database.Update(AgencyAddressList,false)); }
}
public void update_bs() {
List<ID> BSIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Business_Segment__c> BSList = [SELECT id,Name,Business_Segment_Status__c, Effective_Date__c, Future_Status__c FROM Business_Segment__c WHERE Effective_Date__c <=: System.Today() and Future_Status__c <> null];
for(Business_Segment__c bs: BSList){
  bs.Business_Segment_Status__c = bs.Future_Status__c;
  bs.Future_Status__c = null;
  bs.Effective_Date__c = null;
  BSIDList.add(bs.id);
}
if(!BSIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Business_Segment',BSIDList, Database.Update(BSList,false)); }
}
public void update_location_th() {
List<ID> LocTHIDList = new List<ID>();
List<ID> LocIDList = new List<ID>();
List<ID> PCIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Transfer_History__c> LocTHList = [SELECT id, Location_ID_New__c, Source_Entity__c, To__c, Future_Transfer__c from Transfer_History__c WHERE Future_Transfer_Date__c =: System.Today() and Future_Transfer__c = true and Transfer_Entity__c = 'Location'];
List<Account> allLocs = new List<Account>();
List<String> locIdsList = new List<String>();
Map<Id,Account> mapNWEmail = new Map<Id,Account>();
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
Set<Id> ToNWIDs = new Set<Id>();
for(Transfer_History__c transLoc: LocTHList){
  String locIds = transLoc.Location_ID_New__c;
  locIds = locIds.replace(',', '-'+transLoc.To__c+',');
  locIdsList.addAll(locIds.split(','));
  transLoc.Future_Transfer__c = false;
  LocTHIDList.add(transLoc.id);
  ToNWIDs.add(transLoc.To__c);
}
If(ToNWIDs != null ){
accList = [Select Id,Email_address__c from Account where id = :ToNWIDs];
for (Account a : accList){
    mapNWEmail.put(a.id,a);
    system.debug('---Hello@---'+mapNWEmail);
}
}
List<String> locIdwithNwIds= new List<String>();
for(String locWithNW: locIdsList){
  locIdwithNwIds= locWithNW.split('-');
  Account acc= new Account(ID=locIdwithNwIds[0]);   
  acc.parentid=locIdwithNwIds[1];  
 if(acc.email_address__c == null){
  if(mapNWEmail.containskey(acc.parentid)){
  acc.email_address__c = mapNWEmail.get(acc.parentid).email_address__c;
  system.debug('---Hello@@@@@---acc.email_address__c ****'+acc.email_address__c);
  }}                
  allLocs.add(acc);
  LocIDList.add(locIdwithNwIds[0]);
}
COBM.add_stack();   
if(!LocIDList.isEmpty()) { 
  update_batch_status('Account(LocTH)',LocIDList, Database.Update(allLocs,false)); 
  List<Processing_Code__c> pc_recs = new List<Processing_Code__c>();
  for(Processing_Code__c pc_rec: [SELECT id, NW_code__c, agency__r.Nationwide_Code_2__c from Processing_Code__c where agency__c IN :LocIDList]) {
    pc_rec.NW_Code__c = pc_rec.agency__r.Nationwide_Code_2__c;
    pc_recs.add(pc_rec);
    PCIDList.add(pc_rec.id);
  }
  update_batch_status('PC(LocTH)', PCIDList, Database.Update(pc_recs,false));
}
COBM.remove_stack();
if(!LocTHIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Transfer_History(Loc)',LocTHIDList, Database.Update(LocTHList,false)); }
}
public void update_pc_th() {
List<ID> PCTHIDList = new List<ID>();
List<ID> PCIDList = new List<ID>();
List<Transfer_History__c> PCTHList = [SELECT id, Bill_to_PC_Clear__c,Location_ID_New__c, Source_Entity__c, To__c, Future_Transfer__c, To__r.nationwide_code_2__c from Transfer_History__c WHERE Future_Transfer_Date__c =: System.Today() and Future_Transfer__c = true and Transfer_Entity__c = 'Processing Code'];
System.debug('---PCTHList --' +PCTHList );
List<Processing_Code__C> allPCs= new List<Processing_Code__C>();
List<String> pcIdsList= new List<String>();
Map<String, String> PC_ID_NW_Code_Map = new Map<String, String>();
Map<Id,Account> mapLocEmail = new Map<Id,Account>();
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
Set<Id> ToLocIDs = new Set<Id>();
for(Transfer_History__c transPC: PCTHList){
  String pcIds= transPC.Location_ID_New__c;
  pcIds= pcIds.replace(',', '-'+transPC.To__c+'-'+transPC.Bill_to_PC_Clear__c+',');
  pcIdsList.addAll(pcIds.split(','));
  transPC.Future_Transfer__c = false;
  for(String pc_id: pcIdsList) { PC_ID_NW_Code_Map.put(pc_id.split('-')[0], transPC.To__r.nationwide_code_2__c); }
  PCTHIDList.add(transPC.id);
  ToLocIDs.add(transPC.To__c);
}
If(ToLocIDs != null ){
accList = [Select Id,Email_address__c from Account where id = :ToLocIDs];
for (Account a : accList){
    mapLocEmail.put(a.id,a);
    system.debug('---Preety@12---'+mapLocEmail);
}
}
List<String> pcWithLocIds= new List<String>();
for(String pcWithLoc: pcIdsList){
  pcWithLocIds= pcWithLoc.split('-');
  Processing_Code__C pc= new Processing_Code__C(ID=pcWithLocIds[0]);                    
  pc.Agency__c=pcWithLocIds[1];
  if(pcWithLocIds[2]=='True'){                    
    pc.Bill_to_pc__c = 'None';
    pc.Bill_to_PC_Val__c = '';
  }
  pc.NW_Code__c = PC_ID_NW_Code_Map.get(pcWithLocIds[0]); 
  if(pc.pc_email_address__c == null){
  if(mapLocEmail.containskey(pc.Agency__c)){
  pc.pc_email_address__c = mapLocEmail.get(pc.Agency__c).email_address__c;
  system.debug('---Hello@@@@@---acc.email_address__c ****'+pc.pc_email_address__c);
  }}  
  allPCs.add(pc);
  PCIDList.add(pcWithLocIds[0]);
}
COBM.add_stack();
if(!PCIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Processing_Code(TH)',PCIDList, Database.Update(allPCs,false)); }
COBM.remove_stack(); // RMO 04MAR14 Def #1041
if(!PCTHIDList.isEmpty()) { update_batch_status('Transfer_History(PC)',PCTHIDList, Database.Update(PCTHList,false)); }
}
public void update_batch_status(String obj_name, List<ID> input_list, List<Database.SaveResult> Results) {
List<Batch_Status__c> batch_status_recs = new List<Batch_Status__c>();
List<String> remarks = new List<String>();
String Status = 'Success';
String record_id = '';
Integer i = 0;
for(Database.SaveResult result: Results) {    
  if(result.isSuccess()) {
    Status = 'Success';
    record_id = result.getId();
    remarks.add('Record Successfully updated');
  }
  else {
    Status = 'Fail';
    record_id = input_list[i];
    for(Database.Error err : result.getErrors()) {
      remarks.add(err.getMessage());
    }
  }
  batch_status_recs.add(new Batch_Status__c(  object_name__c = obj_name,
                                              Status__c = status,
                                              record_id__c = record_id,
                                              remarks__c = String.join(remarks,'\n'),
                                              batch_datetime__c = datetime.now()
                                           ));
  remarks.clear();
  i++;
}
try {
  insert batch_status_recs;
} catch(Exception bat_e) {
  COBM.email_riyaz(obj_name + '-> update_batch_status() on ' + sandbox + ' Error - ' + bat_e.getmessage());
}
}
}
```

May anyone please explain me the flow of these classes?

Comment: Please help me with what are these classes doing. I am very new to Batch Apex.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla flow of your 3 classes:

1. Control flows from `BatchJob_Obs` to `BatchUpdateOBS` and from here to `BatchUpdate`
2. The first class `BatchJob_Obs` is scheduler class which decides when to run a BatchJob i.e. `BatchUpdateOBS`. `BatchJob_Obs` job can be schedule using `System.schedule()`. Scheduler will run as per the cron expression specified and will execute the `BatchUpdateOBS` batch job. Once Batch Job starts running it will call `BatchUpdate` methods (I think it's a helper class) and does some operation.